# Assigning a Keyboard Shortcut to Reindent XML - Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to the Notepad++ command "Reindent XML"?

This menu item is found under TextFX -> TextFX HTML Tidy => Tidy: Reindent XML.

I use this very, very frequently (and repeatedly on batches of 5-8 files), and it's annoying to do it by mouse. I looked through the Settings -> Shortcut Mapper ... menu item, but I didn't see any way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expected it to be listed under Shortcut mapper -> Plugin commands, but I didn't see it (too bad there's no way to search or at least sort that list).

An alternative that I use is the [XML Tools plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/).  I have a shortcut for "Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.